# How to install memcached in PHP 8.1 using Wamp Server

Tags: wamp, memcached, php-8.1, wamp64

I need to set up memcached in my application, I am using PHP 8.1 and Wamp is my local server.

I have added php_memcached.dll file in my php ext folder and also extension=php_memcached.dll added in php.ini.

After that I have restarted my Wamp I have checked phpinfo details but I couln't found memcached version details.

I have noticed in my logs "PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_pthreads.dll'"

If anyone knows how to sort out the problem, Please share the steps.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Are you using `php_pthreads.dll` as these 2 things are not related

Comment: Did you download and install the Thread Safe version of Memcached? That would be the correct version for WAMPServer

Comment: Does not look like that has been maintained since php5.6, it may be it no longer works

Comment: You do know you also need to install the MemCached server as well as the dll which only links PHP to memcached. I cannot find a current version of this compiled and ready to go on a windows system? Can you??

Comment: Same issue here. Any idea? i also want it for PHP 8.1 version

Here is the link i guess https://pecl.php.net/package/memcache